# Can one Sqlite db support interaction by two server programs all on the raspberry pi

Tags: sqlite

Say you are running two server programs on a single raspberry pi.
Can they both interact with a SQLite db at the same time?

Or seem to be happening at the same time as requests wait for each other to be executed???

Comment: Note that SQLite is [Officially Recommended](http://sqlite.org/whentouse.html) for use on embedded devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SQLite supports this.

Historically, the concurrency model in SQLite worked like this:

- Readers don't block other readers, and
- Writers block all other readers and writers during the short time it takes to write the data.
- Transactions use read-after-write verification, which can have some [performance implications on spindle hard drives for multiple inserts](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Nowadays the situation is a bit more nuanced.  [SQLite Version 3.0.0](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) introduced a new locking and journaling mechanism designed to improve concurrency over SQLite version 2 and to reduce the writer starvation problem.  SQLite 3 also supports a [Write-Ahead Journal](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

The upshot is that SQLite is perfectly capable of handling "medium-concurrency" applications; two server processes on a Raspberry Pi would certainly seem to qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, nothing prevents you from using SQLite concurrently. The feature is [well supported](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

The issue you may encounter is in terms of performance when you do a lot of concurrent writes. Although version 3 of SQLite has a bunch of optimizations, doing a lot of writes could quickly become a bottleneck if you're using an inexpensive (i.e. slow) SD card.